# Where should I put new Session in my project?

Tags: php, class, session

I'm creating post bulletin project.
And in here I create `Session class` to manage `session`.

My `index.php`

```
$bulletin = new Controller_Bulletin();
$bulletin->setParams(array_merge($_GET, $_POST));
$bulletin->execute('index'); // Execute index action
```

My `Controller_Bulletin.php`

```
class Controller_Bulletin extends Controller_Base
{
  ...
  public function index() // My index action
  {
    // Render the index html
    $this->render('bulletin/index.php', get_defined_vars());
  }

  public function insert() // My insert action
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

My `Session class`

```
class Session
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    session_start();
  }
  ...
}
```

I need to load Session class in every action.
Example: index, insert, etc.
But when I put `$session = new Session();` in every action.
My mentor said it is not good.
Maybe because I duplicated it in every action.
Example in `Controller_Bulletin class`

```
public function index()
{
  $session = new Session();
  ...
}

public function insert()
{
  $session = new Session();
  ...
}
```

I'm still not good with OOP.
Can someone give me clue where should I call session object?
If my question still not clear please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about having it like this

```
class Controller_Bulletin extends Controller_Base {

    protected $session;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->session = new Session();
    }

    public function index() { // My index action
        // Render the index html
        // use $this->session here
        $this->render('bulletin/index.php', get_defined_vars());
    }

    public function insert() { // My insert action
        // use $this->session here
    }

}
```

Comment: I already think like that.
Maybe I will try it.
I will update my mentor question later.

Answer (score 0):

You can load `$session = new Session();` on every action. But for that, you have to make a small change on your `public function __construct()`. Change your function to

```
public function __construct()
{
if(session_id() === ""){
     session_start();
}
}
```

This will check if any session started before. If so it wont start again and wont make any errors.

Comment: I already have class to do session_start(); So doing session_start() is meaningless I think.